# Why cannot be `const val` used in build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, constants, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to define a version constant in `guild.gradle.kts` file so that it can be used even in the `plugins` block. The `plugins` block requires [restricted syntax](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax):

> `«plugin version»` must be constant, literal, strings

Following the restriction I tried to define the a version constant:

```
const val kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
}
```

However this fails with message

```
Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects
```

even though the declaration seem to meet all [const requirements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants). Why cannot be `const val` used in build.gradle.kts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though it seems like your build script is top level, it isn't. The gradle docs mentions this when explaining the lifecycle of the build:

> Finally, evaluate each `Project` by executing its `build.gradle` file, if present, against the project.

([source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html)) This means that in your kotlin build scripts, the receiver type (i.e. `this`) is `KotlinBuildScript` which is eventually a subclass of `Project`. I don't know the details about how it's evaluated, but I can imagine it would be equivalent to what you can do in Kotlin with receiver types:

```
fun Project.evaluate(buildScript: Project.() -> Unit) = this.evaluate()
```

So your build script is really just the inside of a closure, hence why you can't use `const val`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a specific Gradle problem (`*.gradle.kts`) but rather a limitation of Kotlin Script (so any `*.kts`) file.

They simply don't support any `const val` assignments yet.

You can check the related YouTrack issue for more info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20110/Kotlin-script-file-doesnt-support-compile-time-constants-const-val-are-only-allowed-on-top-level-or-in-objects